# In xcode and tvos, is it possible to convert the top shelf image to an image stack?

Tags: xcode, parallax, tvos, apple-tv

In xcode, and tvos,  the 3D parallax icons in the asset catalog are shown as image stacks. But this is not the case with the so called *top shelf image*.

Is it possible to convert the top shelf image to a multi layer image stack in xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only content that is focusable is multilayered and then you need to provide several of them.

There are 3 top shelf types, but **unfortunately none of them fit your needs**.

You can read more about them in [apple tv human interface guide lines](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/#top-shelf).

**1) single, static top shelf image**

> Provide a visually rich **static image**. Your app’s static top shelf
>   image is used when dynamic content isn’t provided or is unavailable.
>   Use it as an opportunity to highlight your brand.
>
> Don’t imply interactivity in a static image. **The static top shelf
>   image isn’t focusable**, so it shouldn't include elements that make it
>   appear interactive.

**2) "Dynamic Content Layouts" - "Sectioned Content Row"**

this is for content similar to portrait movie posters. those can be multilayered, but:

> Provide enough content to constitute a complete row. At a minimum,
>   load enough images in a sectioned content row to span the full width
>   of the screen.

**3) "Dynamic Content Layouts" - "Scrolling Inset Banner"**

this is for content similat to wide screen advertising banners. those can be multilayered, but:

> A minimum of three images is recommended for a scrolling banner to
>   feel effective.

Comment: So I conclude that it is NOT possible.

Comment: yes, unless you can go for 3 banners that make sense for your app.

Answer (score 0):

To make Dynamic Content you need [an Apple TV extension](https://www.raywenderlich.com/145257/tvos-top-shelf-tutorial-static-interactive).  To include a layered image in the content use the [Apple Parallax Previewer app](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/CreatingParallaxArtwork.html) to load all the images in the layered image, and export as an LSR file.  Drop the LSR into an Apple TV Extension target.  Use the code below to create a scrolling inset (rather than a sectioned one as in the RW tutorial).  Then read in the file from the app bundle.

Note that the Top Shelf will "scroll through" your images so you probably want 3 related layered images (as the above answer suggests).  You can see what a single image looks like (pretty lame) in [this video](https://youtu.be/wZOzC5Z2gMQ).

```
import Foundation
import TVServices

class ServiceProvider: NSObject, TVTopShelfProvider {

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    // MARK: - TVTopShelfProvider protocol

    var topShelfStyle: TVTopShelfContentStyle {
        // Return desired Top Shelf style.
        return .inset
    }

    var topShelfItems: [TVContentItem] {
        let v1Ident = TVContentIdentifier(identifier: "V1", container: nil)!
        let v1Content = TVContentItem(contentIdentifier: v1Ident)!
        v1Content.imageURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "v1", withExtension: ".lsr")
        // Create an array of TVContentItems.
        return [v1Content]
    }

}
```